# Resolve classes of maven dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jibx, maven-jibx

Consider the following dependency hierarchy:

[image: maven dependency hierarchy]

Now I have `maven-jibx-plugin` in project `D` which generates the compiled classes in `target/classes` folder. But when I run my `spring-boot` project `A` the generated classes from project `D` could not be resolved.
Resolve dependencies from workspace is also checked from maven preferences of project `A`

Comment: How is the relation between project A and project D definied in the related project POM files?
Is D a dependency of A or is D a sub-module of A?

Comment: @AnDus Actually, D is adependency of A

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like Eclipse and Maven do not recognize project D as a related project.

There are two possible solutions:

- In Eclipse you can add project D as a dependent project to project A's build path. Go to the project's **Properties** dialog. Select **Java Build Path** and then switch to the  **Projects** tab. There you should add project D.
- Or alternatively you rely on Maven's dependency management. Therefore you have to add a dependency to project A's POM file. First add a `<dependency>` ( if not already done ) to the `<dependencies>` section. **Now comes the important part!** Maven can only resolve this dependency if you have installed the compiled maven artifact ( the jar file ) in your local maven repository. On the shell switch into project D's directory and then run `mvn install`

I hope that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding generated sources folder as a source folder in eclipse? You can do this from eclipse (right click the generated sources or any folder in it > Build Path > Use as Source Folder) or you can use maven build helper plugin by adding something like below to your pom.xml

```
        <!-- MAVEN ADD GENERATED-SOURCES TO CLASSPATH -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.build-helper.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```